# LWJGL Mouse Scroll wheel input

Tags: java, mouse, lwjgl, mousewheel

I would like to know how do I get the following actions using LWJGL's Mouse class:

- When the mouse scroll wheel is scrolled down
- When the mouse scroll wheel is scrolled up
- When the mouse scroll wheel is pressed

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As specified on the [lwjgl javadoc](http://www.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/input/Mouse.html), try calling

```
    Mouse.getDWheel(); // Scroll amount
    Mouse.isButtonDown(2); // Scroll wheel pressed?
```

Answer (score 5):

For LWJGL 3 you may do this

```
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWScrollCallback;

// ...

float mouseWheelVelocity = 0;

GLFW.glfwSetScrollCallback(windowId, new GLFWScrollCallback() {
    @Override public void invoke (long win, double dx, double dy) {
        System.out.println(dy);
        mouseWheelVelocity = (float) dy;
    }
});
```

Replace `windowId` variable with yours. Make sure it's initialized by that time. Then you can save `dy` argument which shows change of the mouse wheel rotation (+1 and -1).